# Potentially Useless Object

Tags: java, oop

As I'm writing `Generic RPG Number 3,742`, I implemented a class for `Items` and `Inventory`. Conceptually, and `Item` is one particular item. I wanted a way to 'stack' items, so that I would only have 1 entry in `Inventory` for each kind of `Item`.

To do this, I created an `Item Wrapper` that has a `private` `Item` and `Number of Items`. It also has a few Methods dealing with getting the total weight of all of these `Items`, etc.

The trouble comes as I expand on this. I find myself wanting to duplicate almost every `Item` Method in my `Item Wrapper` class. The alternative is making the `Item` `public` and referring to it in the `Inventory` class which feels equally as bad.

Is this a sign that `Item Wrapper` shouldn't exist? That creates problems with either duplicate items in `Inventory` or the concept of `Item`s being singular. I feel like there's probably a better solution, but I can't seem to find it.

**EDIT:** Adding more clarification as to current class structure.

`Player_Character` has a private `Inventory`.

`Inventory` has a private [mumble] `Vector` of `Item Wrapper`s.

`Item Wrapper` had a private `Item` and private `int` "how_many".

Note the 'had.' As I've been expanding on `Inventory`, I've noticed that I've been needing `Item_Name` or other things specific to `Item`. If I don't change my design, I either copy all of the `Get` functions in `Item` into `Item Wrapper` or make `Item` public (in `Item Wrapper`).

Comment: have you considered a collection of `Item`s? A `wrapper` typically encloses a single instance, just like candy.

Comment: Exposing item methods in a wrapper doesn't make sense to me. A collection of items is not an item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're making the problem more complex than it needs to be. You could simplify the problem by adding a `quantity` field to the `Item` and providing a method to calculate the total weight with the `quantity` and `weight`. Your `ItemWrapper` isn't adding anything that an additional field and method can't do.

Comment: If you want to treat groups of items as a single item, then the `ItemWrapper` type is useful (see my earlier answer).

Comment: @GregBrown I guess another part of the question is "Is the concept of a single item useful? Could it easily be replaced with 'one or more item?'"

Comment: @RowlandB I just took a closer look at your original question. It seems odd to me to have a public `ItemWrapper` type but a private `Item` type. If you truly only need to store an item's type and an associated quantity, then maybe you could just use a map of type to quantity, where the map key is the item type. The map value would be the number of items of that type.

Comment: @GregBrown This was my suggestion but it seems the op isn't convinced.

Answer (score 5):

Your `ItemWrapper` type sounds like it might be an example of a [composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), which is a very common design pattern. If so, I wouldn't consider it redundant or useless.

Comment: The link you shared talks about `Tree Structures` which isn't really what I'm looking for. Does the composite design pattern have to be a `Tree`?

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing screams out to me as something a `Map` does very well. Why don't you have an `Inventory` implementation something like the following;

```
public class Inventory {

private static final int MAX_SIZE = 10;

private final Map<Type, List<Item>> inventoryItems = new HashMap<Type, List<Item>>();

// Keep track of the total number of items in the inventory
private int totalSize;

public void add(Item item) {

    // If the total size is greater than the max then don't allow the operation...
    if(totalSize == MAX_SIZE){      
        throw new IllegalStateException("Exceeded maximum size");
    }

    if (!inventoryItems.containsKey(item.getType())) {
        inventoryItems.put(item.getType(), new ArrayList<Item>());
    }

    inventoryItems.get(item.getType()).add(item);

    totalSize++;
}

public List<Item> getItems(Type type) {
    return inventoryItems.get(type);
}

public int getTotalWeight() {

    int total = 0;

    for (List<Item> items : inventoryItems.values()) {
        total += calculateTotalWeight(items);
    }

    return total;
}

public int getTotalWeightByType(Type type) {
    return calculateTotalWeight(inventoryItems.get(type));
}

private int calculateTotalWeight(List<Item> items) {
    int total = 0;

    for (Item item : items) {
        total += item.getWeight();
    }

    return total;
}

public void remove(Item item) {
    // Remove the item from inventoryItems and decrement the count
    totalSize--;
}

}
```

Removes the need for your `ItemWrapper` class.

You would then have a `Character` class that can look something along the lines of...

```
public class Character {

private final String name;

... // Any other fields

private final Inventory inventory;

public Character(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.inventory = new Inventory();
}

...

public void addToInventory(Item item) {
    inventory.add(item);
}

public List<Item> getItemsByType(Type type) {
    return inventory.getItems(type);
}

public void removeFromInventory(Item item) {
    inventory.remove(item);
}

...

}
```

**NOTE:**
You mention that you are using `Vector` which has the overhead of synchronization on every operation (probably unnecessary). I really see no issue with you using a `Map`...

Comment: What does using a `Map` give me? The point of `Item Wrapper` is to provide easy counting, but also to save space (conceptually as well as computationally). This solution doesn't necessarily help computationally- is that not an issue in modern computing?

Comment: @RowlandB I feel like you're over-complicating your problem.

Comment: I'm just not familiar with `Map`s, so I'm trying to wrap (hah!) my head around them before accepting anything.